# Changing title color in androidplot pie chart without xml

Tags: android, androidplot

I am generating the pie chart dynamically inside a `HorizontalScrollView`. When I do so the title of the pie chart is set to white by default. How can I change it without XML(as I have no XML). Below is the code that I used to generate the chart dynamically.

```
LinearLayout l_layout=chart_container;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_view = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,300);

PieChart pie = new PieChart(this,"BYE");

s1 = new Segment("s1", 10000);
s1.setTitle("10000");
s2 = new Segment("s2", 5000);
s2.setTitle("5000");

SegmentFormatter sf1 = new SegmentFormatter(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.pie_segment_formatter1);
sf1.getOuterEdgePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

SegmentFormatter sf2 = new SegmentFormatter(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.pie_segment_formatter2
sf2.getOuterEdgePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

pie.addSeries(s1, sf1);
pie.addSeries(s2, sf2);
pie.getBorderPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
pie.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

pie.getRenderer(PieRenderer.class).setDonutSize(0.1f,PieRenderer.DonutMode.PERCENT);
pie.redraw();


l_layout.addView(pie, lp_view);

setupIntroAnimation(pie);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
pie.getTitle().getLabelPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
```